# Assert Failure crashing Kestrel after migrating to .NET Core 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, .net-core-2.0

We've recently ported our codebase to use .NET Core 2.0, away from .NET Framework 4.7 + ASP.NET Core 2.0.

We're now getting random crashes in Kestrel that look like this:

```
Assert Failure
Expression: [Recursive resource lookup bug]
Application is shutting down...
Description: Infinite recursion during resource lookup within System.Private.CoreLib.  This may be a bug in System.Private.CoreLib, or potentially in certain extensibility points such as assembly resolve events or CultureInfo names.  Resource name: ArgumentNull_Generic
Stack Trace:
  at System.SR.InternalGetResourceString(String key)
  at System.SR.GetResourceString(String resourceKey, String defaultString)
  at System.ArgumentNullException..ctor(String paramName)
  at System.Runtime.Loader.AssemblyLoadContext.GetLoadContext(Assembly assembly)
  at System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFromResolveHandler(Object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
  at System.AppDomain.OnAssemblyResolveEvent(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String assemblyFullName)
  at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks, IntPtr ptrLoadContextBinder)
  at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalGetSatelliteAssembly(String name, CultureInfo culture, Version version, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
  at System.Resources.ManifestBasedResourceGroveler.GetSatelliteAssembly(CultureInfo lookForCulture, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
  at System.Resources.ManifestBasedResourceGroveler.GrovelForResourceSet(CultureInfo culture, Dictionary`2 localResourceSets, Boolean tryParents, Boolean createIfNotExists, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
  at System.Resources.ResourceManager.InternalGetResourceSet(CultureInfo requestedCulture, Boolean createIfNotExists, Boolean tryParents, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
  at System.Resources.ResourceManager.InternalGetResourceSet(CultureInfo culture, Boolean createIfNotExists, Boolean tryParents)
  at System.Resources.ResourceManager.GetString(String name, CultureInfo culture)
  at System.SR.InternalGetResourceString(String key)
  at System.SR.GetResourceString(String resourceKey, String defaultString)
  at System.ArgumentNullException..ctor(String paramName)
  at System.Runtime.Loader.AssemblyLoadContext.GetLoadContext(Assembly assembly)
  at System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFromResolveHandler(Object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
  at System.AppDomain.OnAssemblyResolveEvent(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String assemblyFullName)
  at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks, IntPtr ptrLoadContextBinder)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalGetSatelliteAssembly(String name, CultureInfo culture, Version version, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Resources.ManifestBasedResourceGroveler.GetSatelliteAssembly(CultureInfo lookForCulture, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Resources.ManifestBasedResourceGroveler.GrovelForResourceSet(CultureInfo culture, Dictionary`2 localResourceSets, Boolean tryParents, Boolean createIfNotExists, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Resources.ResourceManager.InternalGetResourceSet(CultureInfo requestedCulture, Boolean createIfNotExists, Boolean tryParents, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Resources.ResourceManager.InternalGetResourceSet(CultureInfo culture, Boolean createIfNotExists, Boolean tryParents)
   at System.Resources.ResourceManager.GetString(String name, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.SR.InternalGetResourceString(String key)
   at System.SR.GetResourceString(String resourceKey, String defaultString)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException..ctor(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
```

Apparently this issue is known and has already been fixed (https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/12668), but has not been released yet.

Has anyone else experienced this issue and found a workaround? It gets triggered  a lot. I've tried the suggestions on the related GitHub issues but none of them work (adding in `new ArgumentException()` into the start of `Main()`, or using en-US culture only).

Comment: any updates on this topic?

Comment: See https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/14033 - basically, have to wait for 2.0.2 release in a few weeks or so.